# Using patch() to mock something that I don't explicilty import

Tags: python, python-unittest

Let's say I have the following modules:

```py
# src/myapp/utils.py
import thirdparty
from myapp.secrets import get_super_secret_stuff

def get_thirdparty_client() -> return thirdparty.Client:
    thirdparty.Client(**get_super_secret_stuff())
```

```py
# src/myapp/things.py
from myapp.utils import get_thirdparty_client
from myapp.transformations import apply_fairydust, make_it_sparkle

def do_something(x):
    thirdparty_client = get_thirdparty_client()
    y = thidparty_client.query(apply_fairydust(x))
    return make_it_sparkle(y)
```

Assume that `myapp` is lightly-tested legacy code, and refactoring is out of the question. Also assume (annoyingly) that `thirdparty.Client` does non-deterministic network I/O in its `__init__` method. Therefore I intend to mock the `thirdparty.Client` class itself so as to make this `do_something` function testable.

Assume also that I must use `unittest` and cannot use another test framework like Pytest.

It seems like the `patch` function from `unittest.mock` is the right tool for the job. However, I'm unsure of how to apply the usual admonition to "patch where it is used."

Ideally I want to write a test that looks something like this:

```py
# tests/test_myapp/test_things.py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

from myapp.things import do_something

def gen_test_pairs():
    # Generate pairs of expected inputs and outputs
    ...

class ThingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('????')
    def test_do_something(self, mock_thirdparty_client):
        for x, y in gen_test_pairs:
            with self.subTest(params={'x': x, 'y': y}):
                mock_thirdparty_client.query.return_value = y
                self.assertEqual(do_something(x), y)
```

My problem is that I don't know what to write in place of the `????`, because I never actually import `thirdparty.Client` in `src/myapp/things.py`.

Options I considered:

1. Apply the patch at `myapp.utils.thirdparty.Client`, which makes my test fragile and dependent on implementation details.
2. "Break the rules" and apply the patch at `thirdparty.Client`.
3. Import `get_thirdparty_client` in the test, use `patch.object` on it, and set its `return_value` to another `MagicMock` that I create separately, and this second mock would stand in for `thirdparty.Client`. This makes for more verbose testing code that can't easily be applied as a single decorator.

None of these options sounds particularly appealing, but I don't know which is considered the least bad.

Or is there another option available to me that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is 2: apply the patch to `thirdparty.Client`.

This is correct because it does NOT in fact break the "patch where it is used" rule.

The rule is intended to be descriptive, not literal. In this case, `thirdparty.Client` is considered to be "used" in the `thirdparty` module.

This concept is described in more detail in the 2018 PyCon talk "Demystifying the Patch Function" by Lisa Roach. The full recording is available on YouTube here: https://youtu.be/ww1UsGZV8fQ?t=537. The explanation of this particular case starts at approximately 9 minutes into the video.